# Should tags ambient and ambient-data-framework be merged?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I propose to merge [ambient](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ambient) and [ambient-data-framework](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ambient-data-framework).

Comment: Are we just voting on Ambient Data or will this set a precedence for other tags?

Comment: My question did not propose which of the two tags to use.
 I think we need a naming convention, which we implicitly set by renaming ADF. Some folks 'voted' for tag:ambient-data-framework. others for tag:adf. I like the idea of spelling things our, so tag:ambient-data-framework, easy to read, understand, and SEO friendly. But... we then also have to rename tag:ecl to tag:external-content-library, and so on. Is that the naming convention we want? If so, we can set up a new Tridion meta question for the tag naming convention and vote on it.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah - I 'd think so... would also consider ADF as a useful synonym.

It seems you need a score of at least 5 in the specific tag to submit or vote on a tag synonym. Maybe interesting to chase up the people with rep on those tags

Comment: chasing up ppl with rep on those tags can work, but if we can gather up some group of ppl here that are in agreement, then a moderator can sort it directly.

Answer (score 4):

I agree as all three ([ambient](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ambient) [ambient-data-framework](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ambient-data-framework) [adf](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adf)) would indicate the same, but which one would you all like to see as the master?

Note, the master will be the one which shows up in the questions, even if they are tagged with one of the synonyms.

I would think [adf](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adf) might be a suitable master, or else [ambient-data-framework](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ambient-data-framework).

Comment: tag:ambient-data-framework is more descriptive and search friendly

Comment: tbh - "ambient" can go. The question it's on should just get re-tagged.

Comment: We can't really delete tags, so when just retagging that question, we will always have the [tag:ambient] tag, which is where synonyms come in, that basically hides it as it will only show the master

Comment: I prefer [adf]. We have other abbreviations as well, like [ecl]. The tag info can explain that adf is about the Ambient Data Framework etc.

Comment: Agree with having synonyms for these terms have mixed feelings about adf vs. ambient-data-framework (and to be honest many of our TLA tags as they are not that search engine friendly.)

Comment: I agree with Glenn, but vote [tag:adf]. Adding `Tridion` (i.e. `Tridion adf`) helps with search (and actually pulls more, possibly false(?), results than `Tridion ambient data framework` on Google). Using  personalized search is even scarier. :-) I'd focus on what makes sense to this community followed by what potential new users might search for, which might be a specific issue (e.g. stack trace, API question, or functionality). I suspect they'll find the right Q&A regardless if we tag with a TLA or the full name.

Comment: Bart, should we pull the trigger on this? Make `adf` the master and merge the other to terms into it?

Comment: @GlennStevens I'm still not happy with it mainly being my choice, let me see if I can rally up some more people and get their opinions in here.

Comment: I like ambient-data-framework  - it is clear - all the TLAs are bad for SEO and can confuse inexperienced users

Answer (score 2):

I "voted" for `adf` in a comment to Bart, but I'm suggesting `ambient-data-framework` as the master tag.

In addition to everyone's points on SEO and how acronyms can confuse new users, also consider that acronyms can:

- **Change**. Did you notice the 2013 docs using `CM` instead of `CME`? What about `SiteEdit` vs `New UI` vs `XPM`?
- **Conflict**. For example, [SDL Campaign Manager](http://www.sdl.com/products/campaign-manager/) is another SDL product. If we have integration questions here, should it be tagged `CM`?
- **Be Seen Out-of-Context**. As an example, companies (like mine) may ask their staff to add signatures to emails and footers to documents, even for short responses to colleagues. You never know when and where something will be read.

A proper tag can help give Stack Exchange questions context if seen via RSS, email, on other sites, or even years later.

Comment: +1 good point. I agree with Alvin, Rob, Glenn and Chris. for all reasons mentioned in this thread, let's go for ambient-data-framework. let's also rename others like tag:ecl