# Tag for SDL Intelligent Marketing Suite (CMA)?

Tags: discussion

I wasn't sure how to tag this question:
[Context Expression Extension Setup](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/3762/46)

**Thoughts or preference on how to tag "SDL Intelligent Marketing Suite"-related questions?** I think [cma](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cma) would make a good synonym, but we probably want a full phrase as discussed in: "[Should tags ambient and ambient-data-framework be merged?](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/q/232/46)."

*This would only be for questions related to its integration with SDL Tridion in the Content Manager or in Content Delivery.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed with the synonym approach as the names were changed a few times.

The ***name Intelligent Marketing Suite*** (or ***IMS***) came only more recently. It is a collection of the products which individually are better known to people.

The most well known product names are ***Campaign Manager*** and ***Email Manager*** which were around the market for years with Alterian. ***Customer Analytics*** is another one which had synonyms like ***Engagement Analytics*** and possibly ***Alchemy***. The word "Alchemy" is known to the market as well, but it was a more recent thing, too. In terms of integrating with CMS (before SDL took over), there is also a name ***Web Journey*** that feed site visiting data back for analytics / campaigns.

So I guess all individual product names are candidates for tags, too.

Comment: That's a nice clarification on the parts of IMS, thanks Hao. I think we'll go with product names (as or when documented) and make note that IMS is a suite itself.

Answer (score 1):

Because I do not know the product, and that it doesn't have a direct correspondence to the current name of the product [cma](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cma) seems like it might cause confusion.

So, for me  [intelligent-marketing-suite](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intelligent-marketing-suite) would be a more meaningful tag.

However, as I pointed out, I don't know the product so I'm not really the target for questions with this tag. Do people who currently know the product refer to it as CMA or as the Intelligent Marketing Suite, or IMS or some other way?

And to further expand on that, do people who are newly exposed to the product know it as CMA or is that just a legacy TLA that only veterans of the SDL world would have the context for?

Regardless of which way we go, we can make one tag the primary and the other a synonym pointing to the one we decide should be the primary.

Comment: I've heard all three: CMA, Intelligent Marketing Suite, and IMS. I think we'll know better after more implementations but I like the approach of using tag that gives more context along with synonyms.